# zsh autocompletion not working on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, zsh

I am on win7 64b, with cywgin 1.7.
I have added zsh shell to the installation.

If I start a shell like with bash:

```
bash --login -i
```

autocompletion works fine straight away. But if I start a zsh:

```
zsh -l -i
```

I get a zsh, but a number of commands echoed in my console, not sure if that is normal or not, and it looks like it expect user input in the middle of it (I append the whole echoed thing in the end):

```
  Ignore insecure $_i_q and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]? "
```

and autocompletion does not at all...

The whole echoed stuff:

```
C:\cygwin\bin>zsh -l -i
compdump () {
        # undefined
        builtin autoload -XUz
}
compinit () {
        emulate -L zsh
        setopt extendedglob
        typeset _i_dumpfile _i_files _i_line _i_done _i_dir _i_autodump=1
        typeset _i_tag _i_file _i_addfiles _i_fail=ask _i_check=yes _i_name
        while [[ $# -gt 0 && $1 = -[dDiuC] ]]
        do
                case "$1" in
                        (-d) _i_autodump=1
                                shift
                                if [[ $# -gt 0 && "$1" != -[dfQC] ]]
                                then
                                        _i_dumpfile="$1"
                                        shift
                                fi ;;
                        (-D) _i_autodump=0
                                shift ;;
                        (-i) _i_fail=ign
                                shift ;;
                        (-u) _i_fail=use
                                shift ;;
                        (-C) _i_check=
                                shift ;;
                esac
        done
        typeset -gA _comps _services _patcomps _postpatcomps
        typeset -gA _compautos
        typeset -gA _lastcomp
        if [[ -n $_i_dumpfile ]]
        then
                typeset -g _comp_dumpfile="$_i_dumpfile"
        else
                typeset -g _comp_dumpfile="${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zcompdump"
        fi
        typeset -ga _comp_options
        _comp_options=(bareglobqual extendedglob glob multibyte nullglob rcexpandparam unset NO_allexport NO_aliases NO_cshnullglob NO_cshjunkiequotes NO_errexit NO_globsubst NO_histsubstpattern NO_ignore
        typeset -g _comp_setup='local -A _comp_caller_options;
             _comp_caller_options=(${(kv)options});
             setopt localoptions localtraps ${_comp_options[@]};
             local IFS=$'\'\ \\t\\r\\n\\0\''
             exec </dev/null;
             trap - ZERR
             local -a reply
             local REPLY'
        typeset -ga compprefuncs comppostfuncs
        compprefuncs=()
        comppostfuncs=()
        : $funcstack
        compdef () {
                local opt autol type func delete eval new i ret=0 cmd svc
                local -a match mbegin mend
                emulate -L zsh
                setopt extendedglob
                if (( ! $# ))
                then
                        print -u2 "$0: I need arguments"
                        return 1
                fi
                while getopts "anpPkKde" opt
                do
                        case "$opt" in
                                (a) autol=yes  ;;
                                (n) new=yes  ;;
                                ([pPkK]) if [[ -n "$type" ]]
                                        then
                                                print -u2 "$0: type already set to $type"
                                                return 1
                                        fi
                                        if [[ "$opt" = p ]]
                                        then
                                                type=pattern
                                        elif [[ "$opt" = P ]]
                                        then
                                                type=postpattern
                                        elif [[ "$opt" = K ]]
                                        then
                                                type=widgetkey
                                        else
                                                type=key
                                        fi ;;
                                (d) delete=yes  ;;
                                (e) eval=yes  ;;
                        esac
                done
                shift OPTIND-1
                if (( ! $# ))
                then
                        print -u2 "$0: I need arguments"
                        return 1
                fi
                if [[ -z "$delete" ]]
                then
                        if [[ -z "$eval" ]] && [[ "$1" = *\=* ]]
                        then
                                while (( $# ))
                                do
                                        if [[ "$1" = *\=* ]]
                                        then
                                                cmd="${1%%\=*}"
                                                svc="${1#*\=}"
                                                func="$_comps[${_services[(r)$svc]:-$svc}]"
                                                [[ -n ${_services[$svc]} ]] && svc=${_services[$svc]}
                                                [[ -z "$func" ]] && func="${${_patcomps[(K)$svc][1]}:-${_postpatcomps[(K)$svc][1]}}"
                                                if [[ -n "$func" ]]
                                                then
                                                        _comps[$cmd]="$func"
                                                        _services[$cmd]="$svc"
                                                else
                                                        print -u2 "$0: unknown command or service: $svc"
                                                        ret=1
                                                fi
                                        else
                                                print -u2 "$0: invalid argument: $1"
                                                ret=1
                                        fi
                                        shift
                                done
                                return ret
                        fi
                        func="$1"
                        [[ -n "$autol" ]] && autoload -Uz "$func"
                        shift
                        case "$type" in
                                (widgetkey) while [[ -n $1 ]]
                                        do
                                                if [[ $# -lt 3 ]]
                                                then
                                                        print -u2 "$0: compdef -K requires <widget> <comp-widget> <key>"
                                                        return 1
                                                fi
                                                [[ $1 = _* ]] || 1="_$1"
                                                [[ $2 = .* ]] || 2=".$2"
                                                [[ $2 = .menu-select ]] && zmodload -i zsh/complist
                                                zle -C "$1" "$2" "$func"
                                                if [[ -n $new ]]
                                                then
                                                        bindkey "$3" | read -A opt
                                                        [[ $opt[-1] = undefined-key ]] && bindkey "$3" "$1"
                                                else
                                                        bindkey "$3" "$1"
                                                fi
                                                shift 3
                                        done ;;
                                (key) if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]
                                        then
                                                print -u2 "$0: missing keys"
                                                return 1
                                        fi
                                        if [[ $1 = .* ]]
                                        then
                                                [[ $1 = .menu-select ]] && zmodload -i zsh/complist
                                                zle -C "$func" "$1" "$func"
                                        else
                                                [[ $1 = menu-select ]] && zmodload -i zsh/complist
                                                zle -C "$func" ".$1" "$func"
                                        fi
                                        shift
                                        for i
                                        do
                                                if [[ -n $new ]]
                                                then
                                                        bindkey "$i" | read -A opt
                                                        [[ $opt[-1] = undefined-key ]] || continue
                                                fi
                                                bindkey "$i" "$func"
                                        done ;;
                                (*) while (( $# ))
                                        do
                                                if [[ "$1" = -N ]]
                                                then
                                                        type=normal
                                                elif [[ "$1" = -p ]]
                                                then
                                                        type=pattern
                                                elif [[ "$1" = -P ]]
                                                then
                                                        type=postpattern
                                                else
                                                        case "$type" in
                                                                (pattern) if [[ $1 = (#b)(*)=(*) ]]
                                                                        then
                                                                                _patcomps[$match[1]]="=$match[2]=$func"
                                                                        else
                                                                                _patcomps[$1]="$func"
                                                                        fi ;;
                                                                (postpattern) if [[ $1 = (#b)(*)=(*) ]]
                                                                        then
                                                                                _postpatcomps[$match[1]]="=$match[2]=$func"
                                                                        else
                                                                                _postpatcomps[$1]="$func"
                                                                        fi ;;
                                                                (*) if [[ "$1" = *\=* ]]
                                                                        then
                                                                                cmd="${1%%\=*}"
                                                                                svc=yes
                                                                        else
                                                                                cmd="$1"
                                                                                svc=
                                                                        fi
                                                                        if [[ -z "$new" || -z "${_comps[$1]}" ]]
                                                                        then
                                                                                _comps[$cmd]="$func"
                                                                                [[ -n "$svc" ]] && _services[$cmd]="${1#*\=}"
                                                                        fi ;;
                                                        esac
                                                fi
                                                shift
                                        done ;;
                        esac
                else
                        case "$type" in
                                (pattern) unset "_patcomps[$^@]" ;;
                                (postpattern) unset "_postpatcomps[$^@]" ;;
                                (key) print -u2 "$0: cannot restore key bindings"
                                        return 1 ;;
                                (*) unset "_comps[$^@]" ;;
                        esac
                fi
        }
        typeset _i_wdirs _i_wfiles
        _i_wdirs=()
        _i_wfiles=()
        autoload -Uz compaudit
        if [[ -n "$_i_check" ]]
        then
                typeset _i_q
                if ! eval compaudit
                then
                        if [[ -n "$_i_q" ]]
                        then
                                if [[ "$_i_fail" = ask ]]
                                then
                                        if ! read -q "?zsh compinit: insecure $_i_q, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure $_i_q and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]? "
                                        then
                                                print -u2 "$0: initialization aborted"
                                                unfunction compinit compdef
                                                unset _comp_dumpfile _comp_secure compprefuncs comppostfuncs _comps _patcomps _postpatcomps _compautos _lastcomp
                                                return 1
                                        fi
                                        _i_wfiles=()
                                        _i_wdirs=()
                                else
                                        (( $#_i_wfiles )) && _i_files=("${(@)_i_files:#(${(j:|:)_i_wfiles%.zwc})}")
                                        (( $#_i_wdirs )) && _i_files=("${(@)_i_files:#(${(j:|:)_i_wdirs%.zwc})/*}")
                                fi
                        fi
                        typeset -g _comp_secure=yes
                fi
        fi
        autoload -Uz compdump compinstall
        _i_done=''
        if [[ -f "$_comp_dumpfile" ]]
        then
                if [[ -n "$_i_check" ]]
                then
                        read -rA _i_line < "$_comp_dumpfile"
                        if [[ _i_autodump -eq 1 && $_i_line[2] -eq $#_i_files && $ZSH_VERSION = $_i_line[4] ]]
                        then
                                builtin . "$_comp_dumpfile"
                                _i_done=yes
                        fi
                else
                        builtin . "$_comp_dumpfile"
                        _i_done=yes
                fi
        fi
        if [[ -z "$_i_done" ]]
        then
                typeset -A _i_test
                for _i_dir in $fpath
                do
                        [[ $_i_dir = . ]] && continue
                        (( $_i_wdirs[(I)$_i_dir] )) && continue
                        for _i_file in $_i_dir/^([^_]*|*~|*.zwc)(N)
                        do
                                _i_name="${_i_file:t}"
                                (( $+_i_test[$_i_name] + $_i_wfiles[(I)$_i_file] )) && continue
                                _i_test[$_i_name]=yes
                                read -rA _i_line < $_i_file
                                _i_tag=$_i_line[1]
                                shift _i_line
                                case $_i_tag in
                                        (\#compdef) if [[ $_i_line[1] = -[pPkK](n|) ]]
                                                then
                                                        compdef ${_i_line[1]}na "${_i_name}" "${(@)_i_line[2,-1]}"
                                                else
                                                        compdef -na "${_i_name}" "${_i_line[@]}"
                                                fi ;;
                                        (\#autoload) autoload -Uz "$_i_line[@]" ${_i_name}
                                                [[ "$_i_line" != \ # ]] && _compautos[${_i_name}]="$_i_line"  ;;
                                esac
                        done
                done
                if [[ $_i_autodump = 1 ]]
                then
                        compdump
                fi
        fi
        for _i_line in complete-word delete-char-or-list expand-or-complete expand-or-complete-prefix list-choices menu-complete menu-expand-or-complete reverse-menu-complete
        do
                zle -C $_i_line .$_i_line _main_complete
        done
        zle -la menu-select && zle -C menu-select .menu-select _main_complete
        bindkey '^i' | read -A _i_line
        if [[ ${_i_line[2]} = expand-or-complete ]] && zstyle -a ':completion:' completer _i_line && (( ${_i_line[(i)_expand]} <= ${#_i_line} ))
        then
                bindkey '^i' complete-word
        fi
        unfunction compinit compaudit
        autoload -Uz compinit compaudit
        return 0
}
compinstall () {
        # undefined
        builtin autoload -XUz
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the issue and fix https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1157

The solution is to delete the `.zcompdump` file and restart (which recreates the file).