# zsh completion doesn't work under Cygwin for other drives

Tags: windows-7, shell, cygwin, zsh, tab-completion

I'm on Win7 x64, Cygwin 1.7 and zsh (and using oh-my-zsh). Zsh newbie here.

I've reviewed [zsh autocompletion not working on cygwin](https://superuser.com/questions/489831/zsh-autocompletion-not-working-on-cygwin) and tried the solution there but no luck.

My mount table:

```
 C: on /c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
 D: on /d type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
 F: on /f type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

As you can see, I'm using `/c, /d and /f` for my drives. Part of the reason to change this from the default `/cygdrive` prefix is to maintain compat with Msysgit

Unfortunately after changing the drive prefix, zsh completion doesn't work

typing `cd /f/code/Por<tab>` no longer completes the folder or present options. It works fine in Bash though :(

If I cd into `/f` and then type `cd Por` - completion works.

How do I make it work everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution has the drawback of having to specify each and every drive, but it works for me:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' fake-files   '/:c' '/:d'
```

Comment: Listing drives can be automated: https://github.com/agross/dotfiles/blob/master/cygwin/completion.zsh#L4

Comment: Very very nice, thank you for sharing such a niche solution :)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. If found out a solution:
http://blog.en.edaro.net/2014/01/fix-broken-autocompletion-with-zsh-in.html

In my situation, the problem occurs only, when running cygwin as another user as you installed cygwin. And it may only occur, when this running user is an administrator (not tested with unprivileged user). The problem may be: As Administrator, you can "always" modify files, even if chmod disallows this. compinit does not know about this situation (its a unix app), but it finds out, that you have write acess to it - that's the problem.